# Find rows in matrix where entries match certain constraints?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in Matlab and want to find the indeces of all rows, where *some* of the columns meet a specific criteria.

Example

```
M =

 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10    14
10    14    11    15
 4     8    10    14
```

Now I want to find the incedeces of all rows, where `M(:,3) == 10 AND M(:,4) == 14`.

The result should be:

```
R =

 0
 1
 0
 1
```

I though about something like

```
find(ismember(M,[* * 10 14]),1)
```

but `ismember()` won't work with wildcars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
R = (M(:,3) == 10 & M(:,4) == 14);
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: This is far too easy. Nice answer!