# Find rows with a specific value in their columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find rows in matrix where entries match certain constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969521/find-rows-in-matrix-where-entries-match-certain-constraints)

In Matlab, i have a matrix (MxN) and I want to find the rows whose entry in a specific column is equal to a specified value. For example, I have a matrix as follow:

```
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   1    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
   0    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0    1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I want to find the rows whose 7th element us equal to `1`. In this example, the result matrix should contains rows 2 and 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if your matrix is called `A`, just do:

```
A(A(:,7)==1,:)
```

PS: I think that this question has already been answered a million times...

Comment: tnx Oli, I know it was a silly question, but for a moment I was confused with a big matrix! :(

Comment: @ Oli: another question: how I should change your code if I want to select a column (or columns) that is/are between for example a and b? I mean, not an exact value, but a range

Comment: found it, I used && instead of &!!